# Ordinary-Least-Squares Estimator of Slope Identities

Tags: statistics, regression, least-squares

Show that the standard formula of the OLS estimator of the slope can be rewritten as: 
$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X})Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2} $$
after using (and proving) that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})Z = 0$ for a non-varying variable $Z$.

My work below, starting with the proof.

\begin{align*}
& \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})Z = 0\\
& \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iZ-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\bar{X}Z = 0\\
& \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iZ = n\bar{X}Z\\
& \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iZ = \bar{X}Z\\
& \bar{X}Q = \bar{X}Q\\
\end{align*}

Now that that's out of the way...

\begin{align*}
\beta_1 & = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iY_i-\bar{Y}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \bar{X}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i + n\bar{X}\bar{Y}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 - 2\bar{X}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i + n\bar{X}^2}\\
& = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iY_i-\frac{\bar{Y}}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \frac{\bar{X}}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i + \bar{X}\bar{Y}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 - 2\frac{\bar{X}}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i + \bar{X}^2}\\
& = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iY_i - \bar{X}\bar{Y}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 - 2\bar{X}^2}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iY_i - n\bar{X}\bar{Y}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 - 2n\bar{X}^2}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iY_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 - \frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2}\\
&*  = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iY_i - \bar{X}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 - \frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X})Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 - \frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X})Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 - 2n\bar{X}^2}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X})Y_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 - 2\bar{X}^2}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X})Y_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 - 2\frac{\bar{X}}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i + \bar{X}^2}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X})Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2}\\
\end{align*}

I don't see how the proof was useful to the problem. I feel that I may have messed up when pulling out the $Y_i$ variable from the sum because it is varying, unlike $Z$ (the line is starred). Would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be much shorter. Recall that $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=n\bar{x}_n$, thus

\begin{align}
\hat{\beta}_1=&\frac{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})(Y_i-\bar{Y})}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\\
=&\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})Y_i - \sum (x_i-\bar{x})\bar{Y}}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\\
=&\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})Y_i - n\bar{x}\bar{Y}+n\bar{x}\bar{Y}}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\\
=&\frac{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})Y_i}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: I still don't understand why proving $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})Z = 0$ was necessary for the problem. Did you make use of it somehow...?

Comment: Actually, this is the only thing that you need in order to prove the equality. Note that in the classical linear settings $x_i$'s are statistically constant, and $Y_i-\bar{Y}$ is normally distributed r.v.  Hence, the statements are identical.

Comment: Ahh, I think I see it. $\sum (x_i-\bar{x})\bar{Y}$ can be declared 0 by the proof, so that utilizes it (as you showed anyway). Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Yes. I meant $\bar{Y}$ in the previous comment (cannot edit it anymore). Anyway, glad to be of help.